# Facebook Page - Get Post feedback and impression via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get some insights on a list of Posts by a Page on Facebook.

To be specific, I want to get the information highlighted [in this blog pos](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-pages/improving-facebook-page-insights/464477419821)t via the API.

But I can't figure out how, anyone knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's only possible using the "stream" table. So you've got to use FQL to query this data. Using this technique you'll only get the impressions directly. Feedback rate can be calculated by adding #comments and #likes and dividing the result by #impressions. Hope they'll add this to the insights graph api as well.

Answer (score 1):

MartinHN

Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#analytics

If you are trying to aggregate multiple pages or a page other than the requesting app then you may need grant read_insights permissions to your application.
Refer to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/